# Datagridview is adding checkbox column repeatedly

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Studio 2017, SQL Server 2016. The problem is that I have added Checkbox column in my DataGridView but it is repeating itself for 5 times

I have made the code from the below link. It's giving a result but why is it repeating the checkbox column? I am calling a function on ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged, so is there any problem with it? What should I do?

```
Private Sub GetRecords()
        Dim query As String = " select distinct t.CPTCode,t.ServiceName,t.DepartmentName,t.SubName,t.Name as Company,t.bedcatename,t.ServiceCharge "
        query += " from tariffpsri t "
        query += " inner join psrirate p on t.Validid= p.Validid "
        query += " inner join ItemOfService i on t.ServiceId = i.ServiceId "
        query += " where t.DepartmentName= '" + ComboBox2.Text + "' "
        query += " And t.companyid = 1 And i.Active = 1 "
        query += " And Convert(varchar, p.ValidFrom, 111) = '" + ComboBox1.Text + "' "
        query += " order by CPTCode "

        conn = GetConnect()
        conn.Open()
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
            'MsgBox(query)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Using sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Using ds As New DataSet1
                    Using dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

                        sda.Fill(dt)

                        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

                    End Using
                End Using
                End Using
            End Using
            conn.Close()
        Dim headerCellLocation As Point = Me.DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, True).Location

        'Place the Header CheckBox in the Location of the Header Cell.
        headerCheckBox.Location = New Point(headerCellLocation.X + 8, headerCellLocation.Y + 2)
        headerCheckBox.BackColor = Color.White
        headerCheckBox.Size = New Size(18, 18)

        'Assign Click event to the Header CheckBox.
        AddHandler headerCheckBox.Click, AddressOf HeaderCheckBox_Clicked
        DataGridView1.Controls.Add(headerCheckBox)

        'Add a CheckBox Column to the DataGridView at the first position.
        Dim checkBoxColumn As DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn = New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
        checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = ""
        checkBoxColumn.Width = 30
        checkBoxColumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, checkBoxColumn)
        'DataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumn)
        'Assign Click event to the DataGridView Cell.
        AddHandler DataGridView1.CellContentClick, AddressOf DataGridView_CellClick
    End Sub
    Private Sub HeaderCheckBox_Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'Necessary to end the edit mode of the Cell.
        DataGridView1.EndEdit()

        'Loop and check and uncheck all row CheckBoxes based on Header Cell CheckBox.
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim checkBox As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = (TryCast(row.Cells("checkBoxColumn"), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell))
            checkBox.Value = headerCheckBox.Checked
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
        'Check to ensure that the row CheckBox is clicked.
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then

            'Loop to verify whether all row CheckBoxes are checked or not.
            Dim isChecked As Boolean = True
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                If Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("checkBoxColumn").EditedFormattedValue) = False Then
                    isChecked = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            headerCheckBox.Checked = isChecked
        End If
    End Sub
    
Am calling above sub on combobox1 and combobox2 selectedindexchange

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Check-all-and-Uncheck-all-CheckBox-in-DataGridView-in-Windows-Application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSzdM.png
```

Comment: Put your code in your question please

Answer (score 0):

One recommendation I can make without seeing exactly what code you wrote, would be to place a breakpoint in the

```
BindGrid()
```

sub to see if it is getting called multiple times.

Since it is adding the checkbox in that subroutine, if it were called multiple times, it would add a checkbox for each call.

If you share the code you wrote, we may be able to provide more detailed help.

Comment: Now i have added my all code i wrote , pls help me to correct

Comment: Thank you for that! Could you edit the top section so it is also included in the code formatting? I don't have high enough rank in SO to fix that.

Comment: I submitted an edit request for the code cleanup.

In the meantime, could you place a breakpoint inside of your GetRecords() sub?

I am wondering if it is being fired multiple times.